# How can I make this timer start onclick

Tags: javascript, timer

I have made this timer script but I can't seem to make it so ti starts onclick.

Here is my whole code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display( notifier, str ) {
  document.getElementById(notifier).innerHTML = str;
}

function toMinuteAndSecond( x ) {
  return Math.floor(x/60) + ":" + x%60;
}

function setTimer( remain, actions ) {
  (function countdown() {
    display("countdown", toMinuteAndSecond(remain));actions[remain] && actions[remain]();
    (remain -= 1) >= 0 && setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
  })();
}

setTimer(20, {
               20: function () { 
                    display("notifier", "seconds"); 
               },
               1: function () { 
                    display("notifier", "second");
               },

               0: function () { 
                    display("notifier", "seconds");
               }
             }
);
</script>

<!--Start Redirect Countdown-->
<div id="redirect_box" style="display:block;">
Redirecting in <span id="countdown"></span> <span id="notifier"></span>
</div>
<!--End Redirect Countdown-->

<div id="buttonn">Skip >></div>
```

Skip >> is suppose be the button that starts the timer and the ID, countdown is the actual countdown. And, notifier is just an extra ID. 
I hope someone can help

Comment: so where do you bind the onclick callback?

Comment: Better mention it before someone else does: *arguments.callee* is not supported in ES5 strict mode. Doesn't bother me, but some like to moan about it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/Mnqaj/

If so, all you needed to do is grab the `buttonn` element and assign an onclick to it.

That's, ummm,  quite a thingy...

Answer (score 0):

First, this:

```
<div id="buttonn">Skip >></div>
```

should be this:

```
<div id="buttonn">Skip &gt;&gt;</div>
```

Second, where is the code that hooks up the Skip button to your timer?  I don't see it in your question.  If it's missing, then there is no click handler for the button div so that's why nothing gets started.

Third, I would also wonder if you meant for the name to be `"buttonn"` with two n's at the end?  If that's a typo, it could also explain why your event handler isn't getting hooked up.

Comment: I know all this....but I need an explanation when i need to add it.

Before I did this: $('#buttonn').click(function(){ but when i added this to the set timer it didnt work

Comment: Would have saved us a lot of time if you just asked how to hook up a click to the button.  Your post led us to believe you thought you had it hooked up, but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create object properties using number literals. The number will be converted to a string, so better to create them as strings in the first place:

```
   '20': function () {
```

That way there's no ambiguity in the property name.

Running the code, I get the error:

```
document.getElementById(notifier) is null
```

Moving the element with id *countdown* above the script fixes that.

To start the timer "onclick", simply create a function that makes the call to setTimer:

```
function startTimer() {
    setTimer(
        /* setTimer code */
    );
}
```

Then start it from the page:

```
<button onclick="startTimer()">Start timer</button>
```